# Unable to convert Dataframe object to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have been to trying to convert dataframe object to datetime with format Y-m-d. My data looks like:

`pdi.head()`

```
     Date                           Predicted_Linear_Regression
0   [2005-02-16T00:00:00.000000000] 0.000663
1   [1982-02-03T00:00:00.000000000] 0.000666
2   [1995-07-12T00:00:00.000000000] 0.000665
3   [1995-03-13T00:00:00.000000000] 0.000666
4   [2009-05-20T00:00:00.000000000] 0.000658
```

I have tried to convert `Date` column to str and then tried to convert to datetime but not able. Tried to convert it directly but unable to.

Comment: Are items in `Date` lists?

Comment: is than an array with a single DT?

Comment: It seems so its a list but when I do `pdi['Date'].dtype` it gives me `dtype('O')`

Comment: That's because lists are of "object" type to `pandas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Date` column contains lists of dates, not dates. Extract the first element of each list, then convert to datetime:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str[0])
```

Comment: It works if `Date` is list. If the `Date` has type string, then `str[0]` gives you something else.

Answer (score 0):

If your `df.Date` is of type `list`, then try:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(np.array(list(df.Date)).flatten())
```

If it's of type `str`, try:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.str.slice(1,-1))
```

And if lazy:

```
try:
    df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.str.slice(1,-1))
except:
    df.Date = pd.to_datetime(np.array(list(df.Date)).flatten())
```